# Get Entity object in Repository

Tags: php, symfony, repository, entity

I'm learning about Entities and Repositories in Symfony and I want to know if is possible access entity object in its repository.

I have the following code in Controller

```
$account = new Account($username, $password, $email);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$result = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Account')->registerAccount();
```

and then in Repository

```
public function registerAccount() {
    // How access to $account here?
}
```

Should I just pass `$account` to repository function or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass that class instance as an argument.

```
public function register(Account $account)
{
    //$account is accessible here...
}
```

**P.S.** I believe you want a method to persist your Account entities right? Its fine to have a method for that in your repositories.

I would use something like

```
public function save(Account $account)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($account);
    $em->flush();
    return $account;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but being new to Symfony I don't know if it's the correct approach...

Comment: @DrKey IMO its perfectly fine and the repository pattern also encourages doing it (see https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Answer (score 0):

Repository is not a place where you should have an access into your entity instance
.
Following the documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html

In repository you should create a custom function which return a result you need (based on DQL you create), and then call your function on repository in controller.

First you have to tell your entity you create repository

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

This information is in annotation which describe your entity.

Then you create your custom function

```
// src/AppBundle/Repository/ProductRepository.php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM AppBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

As you can see the function findAllOrderedByName() is finding all item in table with product and order asc result.

And finally in a place when you need to have your result (eg. in a Controller) you need to call your repository using created function:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$products = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
    ->findAllOrderedByName();
```

Comment: I suspect you completely missed the point of the question.  Consider going back and seeing what was actually being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest create object manager service like AccountManager which dependence EntityRepository and Entity Class name. This service can include create, update etc functions. After creating this service don't forgot to register it in services.

E.g.
in controller you can create object Account entity

```
$account = new Account();
$account->setUsername($username);
$account->setPassword($password);
$account->setEmail($email);
$accountManager = $this->get('account.manager');
$accountManager->registerAccount($account);
```

Object Manager service

```
<?php
//...

class AccountManager
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /*
     * @var string
     */
    private $entityClassName;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param string $entityClassName
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, $entityClassName)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->entityClassName = $entityClassName;
    }

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @return bool
     */
    public function registerAccount(Account $account)
    {
        try {
             $this->entityManager->persist($account);
             $this->entityManager->flush();
             return true;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
             // logging
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Name something by managers [is a bad idea](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129537/can-manager-classes-be-a-sign-of-bad-architecture).